# Datatype for multidimensional array that keeps growing depending on the previous values of cells

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I am looking for an elegant datatype and method to handle this problem below in Java or dot Net environment (C# or VB.net)

It is a (r x c) matrix of numbers (integers). The 1st column values is a 1D array (range of numbers). The 2nd column takes a  different range of values for each of the 1st column value (so, its basically a 2D jagged-array). The 3rd column has a range of value for each pair of 1st and 2nd column values.(when the 1st and 2nd column is fixed with a value, the 3rd column takes a range of values). The number of columns is not fixed and depends on the user input. It can go up to 20 or even more

How do you handle this problem efficiently in java or C# or VB.net.

I am linking an image to the equation that I want to program. [image http://s08.site50.net/stackov/f1.jpg](http://s08.site50.net/stackov/f1.jpg), in-which C and S are some constants. i=1,2,3...r (number of rows) and k-1=0,1,2,3..c (number of cols). The range of R(i,k-1) depends on maximum and minimum values and MAY also depend on previous values from R(1,k),R(2,k)...R(i-1,k-1) according to the equation. The initial known values are fixed integers (not in a range) for R(1,c), R(2,c),...,R(r,c)

Comment: This is an expression example of what I like to evaluate in the end : V(k-1) = 5-[Sum(i=1 to k-1) of { C(i)+C(i-1)}].   P.S. Value of C(i-1) depends on what value C(i) takes and it might be a range of numbers or a single number. C(i) is a range of numbers. This is just an example of how I like to use the column values in expression.

Comment: Will a `List<List<T>>` (.NET) do it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your requirement correctly.  It sounds to me like each row of your matrix is a recursive data type (lets call it a `MultiJaggedList`), where each object has an `Integer`, plus a list of `MultiJaggedList`s.  So, if you create a `MultiJaggedList<T>` generic class with members of type `T` and `List<MultiJaggedList<T>>`, then you could just use a `List<MultiJaggedList<Integer>>` for your matrix.  Then, the first column of your matrix is the Integers in the objects that are directly in the list.  The values in the second column are the Integers at the next level down in the structure, and so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to evaluate:  ![image](http://s08.site50.net/stackov/f1.jpg).    In the image, C and S are constants. I have thought about recursive datatype and would be glad to find an efficient way to evaluate this expression.

Comment: I don't understand that expression.  First, what are `i` and `k`?  And over what set are the maximum and minimum to be evaluated?

Comment: The one example I gave in my main question is just an example. The image above is the actual problem In that image, the i goes from 1,2,3...r (number of rows); K-1 goes from 0,1,2...c (c=number of columns). The initial values (R(1,c), R(2,c),..R(r,c)) are known (given) and we derive other values from that. P.S: C and S are constants.  The maximum and minimum are the range of values that R(i,k-1) can take when the previous R(1,c) upto R(i-1,k-1) values are known  and in this problem they all may have a range of values according to that condition.